# Change size of one Bootstrap 3 tooltip only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am using `Bootstrap 3` `tooltip` but on one page i want to increase the size of them.

I don't want to affect the rest of the site.

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work so i was wondering if i have the syntax wrong or something.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```css
.dashboard+.tooltip>.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 350px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
           <p>This week:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
           <p id="extTotalThisWk" class="dashboard" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" style="cursor: pointer" data-original-title="
                 <span class='text-left'>
                    <p style='padding-top: 5px'>This total number is made up from:</p>
                    <ul style='padding-bottom: 5px'>
                       <li>Added this week - Deleted this week</li>
                    </ul>
                 </span>">123</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden-xs col-md-1"></div>
     </div>
```

I have also tried it without the `+.tooltip` in the `CSS` but it still doesn't apply it.

Also i have tried the following but still didn't work

```
 <span class='text-left' style='max-width: 350px; width: 350px;'>
```

Obviously if i just use `.tooltip-inner` it works but this affects the whole site which i don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If it is about selecting only that tooltip inside `#extTotalThisWk`, then you can use the `id` as a selector .

```
#extTotalThisWk + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```css
#extTotalThisWk + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 350px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<p id="extTotalThisWk" class="dashboard" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" style="cursor: pointer" data-original-title="
         <span class='text-left' >
            <p>This total is:</p>
            <div>Added this week - Deleted this week</div>
         </span>">
  123</p>
  <p id="extTotalThisWkBis" class="dashboard" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" style="cursor: pointer" data-original-title="
         <span class='text-left' >
            <p>This total is:</p>
            <div>Added this week - Deleted this week</div>
         </span>">
  another one , another id</p>
```

It is about

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
>
> **Specificity** is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied. Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed of different sorts of [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Reference#Selectors).

Comment: I did think of this but i need to use this size across other panel's just on this page and they all have a unique `ID` so i couldn't use `ID`

Comment: @murday1983 unfortunately, we cannot guess the whole structure of your page to see what is commun to those tooltips only, you might need to add a class on the parent for that , i'm afraid we will not be able to help you further :( CSS specifity is one hint, contains() from jQuery could be another one.

Comment: I have tried your solution and for some reason it isn't working. When i inspect the `tooltip` element it hasn't picked it up.  It seems that it only works if i use `.tooltip-inner` only, then it works but this affects the whole site

Comment: .tooltip-inner is the generic class for the container created for every tooltip, that is why i proposed the id of the parent, to select only the one inside this specific id. Your selector must catch,  or a single id or a specific single html structure where the tooltip stands .  adding a class on the closest parent might help, . Or jquery with https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ if your tooltip have a specific similar text that you find only with the tooltip you want to resize

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code inside a `div` and can use `>` selector from parent `class`.Make sure that `span` elements are `inline`, so set them to `block` and give the style to it. Below is the working snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```css
.main-holder>.tooltip>.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: center
}

span.text-left {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-holder">
  <p id="extTotalThisWk" class="dashboard" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" style="cursor: pointer" data-original-title="
         <span class='text-left'>
            <p>This total is:</p>
            <div>Added this week - Deleted this week</div>
         </span>">
    123</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I see it working in your snippet but fpor some reason when i apply your solution (even 'copy' and 'pasting' your code) it still doesn't apply it at all. I have cleared cache everything but it doesnt display the `CSS` in dev tools

Comment: @murday1983 I  have no idea about your code. Something might be overriding it.

Comment: It seems that it only works if i use `.tooltip-inner` only in my `CSS`, then it works but this affects `tooltips` across the whole site